# Usage of "studying books"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I'm not a native English speaker. I was recently chided for wrongly using *studying* as follows:

> acquiring information by **studying books**

Is this really wrong?

Comment: No, it's **not** wrong. One can "study" anything. I acquire information not only by studying books, but also by studying human and animal behavior, the consequences of natural disasters, and the way my PC behaves when I push certain buttons on the PC case and click on certain icons on the PC monitor.

Comment: Thanks! Now how do I make my boos understand, who has been a big shot throughout her life? :)

Comment: Nobody likes being told they're wrong, especially big shots. Sometimes you just have to accept defeat before you've even started to compete. The best strategy in this case is to ask your boss what she thinks you should say. Use that for documents you create for her. Use yours for documents you create for yourself. Sometimes it doesn't pay to be right. I know this isn't what you want to hear, but reality is often more powerful than principle, & accepting reality is often more congenial: [Sir Thomas More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_More) lost his head for foolishly being too principled.

Comment: I understand the general mentality of Indian bosses (I am from India and I'm assuming that Ankush is too). English is one subject they 'boss' over most and never accept what their subordinates say even if what their subordinates say makes a lot of sense. I quite agree with what Bill Franke said in the above comment.

Comment: @Bill: Your advice is well taken. Sadly, there's nothing I can do to ensure I don't make "mistakes" in future. :(

Comment: @InglishTeeture: Yes, I'm from India. Well spotted! That said, my boss certainly knows her English, having held many important positions in foreign universities. I did make a Google search on "studying books" when she pointed this out, and was surprised to see the paucity of results. What irks me is why can't people be tolerant when it comes to usage and certain ambiguous areas of grammar (ending with preposition, split infinitive, etc.). Anyway.

Comment: @ankush At least for this once, you actually need to thank you boss -- for prompting you to explore what you had taken for granted all the time. There is something out there still that we need to check out and learn.

Comment: @Kris You're right. I am indeed thankful for having my interest in language rekindled.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote this:

> . . . acquiring information by studying books.

*Studying* means "closely examining". Since books are normally simply *read*, the word *study* here carries the additional connotation of closely examining a material or something that is difficult to understand at first. This could mean you are examining the cover or the paper of the book, or that you are interpreting the minutiae of the text. It would be most appropriate in situations where you **go over the same page again and again**, trying to understand what it really means:

> *study the Bible as part of one's religion, or as an historic document*
>
> *study a poem in order to understand its deeper meaning*
>
> *study the manual of your television set written in inscrutable Chinglish*

*Study* may or may not be acceptable in your situation: I am undecided. But I think you simply mean *read*, especially since this is about *several* books, and I think that would be the better choice—unless all these books are manuals or other books that normally require rereading sentences and paragraphs and pages in order to fully understand them. So it depends a little bit on context.

Answer (score 2):

*[Study](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/study_18)* can be used in two slightly different senses: *learn about a subject* or *read something very carefully*. Hence, one can study mathematics from a book (first sense) or one can study a mathematics book (second sense). For that matter, one can study this tutorial, that manual, this paper or that contract.

Comment: Yes, but I guess the expression "studying books" has never been very popular. I think I'll drop it from my repertoire.

Comment: Thanks for boosting my confidence! But I can't overlook the fact that the opinion is sharply divided on this. I think I'll file it my memory as another of those "gray areas".

Comment: By  the way, can you show some examples where "studying books" is used by authoritative sources?

Comment: *Studying a book* is not related to *studying books*. There's plenty of semantic difference. That example is not relevant and could effectively distract from the question.

Comment: I agree with @Kris. While statistical analysis can be misleading in general, here we are doing a straight count of two very specific and well understood phrases. Introducing "this" and "that" will just complicate matters. Anyway, please let's not argue about this. :)

Comment: @JasonBourne I can see your point. Believe me it drove me crazy looking for evidence against "studying books". When nothing turned up after furious Google searches, I turned to this community. 

All said and done, my conclusion is that "studying books" is not in common use, so I should be careful in future. Beyond this, I don't think much can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary’s definition 9a of the verb *study* is ‘To read (a book, a passage, an author) with close attention.’

Answer (score 0):

The person who chided you must have assumed that by "studying books" you were observing them rather than reading them.
While your statement is not wrong, given appropriate context, there are always better ways to put the same point forward to remove such kinds of ambiguity when dealing with people less knowledgeable in English.

Example: "acquired information by referring to books", "acquired information by studying the material in books". All these simply depend on the context of the sentence.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, *study*, used in general speech, includes the idea of '*reading a book*', so *studying a book* would be incorrect.

**[stud·y](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20study)** /ˈstədē/
*Noun* The devotion of time and attention to acquiring knowledge on an academic subject, **esp. by means of books**.
*Verb* Devote time and attention to acquiring knowledge on (an academic subject), **esp. by means of books**.
<sup>[emphasis mine]</sup>

Furthermore, the phrase *studying books* fails to convey a focused idea: Are you talking about the process of *studying*, or are you emphasizing the *use of books*, for acquiring information? Saying 'studying books' mixes the two elements. Say instead:

> ...acquiring information by study(ing).  — to mean 'by reading books' or by other forms of '**research**'.
>
> ...acquiring information by reading books.  — to mean using **books** for the purpose.

Comment: Brilliant answer! I guess that's the point. Studying a book and studying a face convey two different things. As I see it, general usage is more inclined toward "reading books". Another day, another lesson!

Comment: @JasonBourne Hmmm, looks like consensus is not in my luck today! But on what should we base our judgment? Ngram also shows that practically no one uses "studying books". I know it's not about correct or incorrect, but looking at contemporary usage I think this answer comes the closest to explaining the reasoning.